# Splitting a string at a comma in java

Tags: java

I have a string with an unknown length that looks like this

`a ,b,  c: integer; d,e :real;`

How could I split this at the commas without getting the words and characters that follow the last commas of the variables? Or is there a way to split the variables at the commas after it is in an array from splitting at the colon? The closest I have come is with this method

```
// the variablesArray would contain a ,b,  c in the first index
// and d,e in the second index.
public static String[] variables(String[]variablesArray) { 
    String variables[] = new String[variablesArray.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < variablesArray.length; i++){
        String temporary = variablesArray[i];
        String arr[] = temporary.split(",");
    }
    return variables;
}
```

When I run this it only returns the first character in the array index

`//prints [a   d]`

Comment: Can you give an example of what output you would like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
String[] result = s.replaceAll("\\w{2,}", "").replaceAll("[:;,]"," ").replaceAll("\\u0020+"," ").split(" ");
```

Array `result` now holds only the single chars. Testing with:

```
for(String c: array)
        System.out.println(c);
```

will output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to break the problem up:

- Split the string at `;`.
- For each of the words you got:

  - Split the string at `:`
  - Insert the first part (list of variable names) into your array.
  - Throw away the second part (type information).

Note that this will give you the array `{"a ,b, c", "d,e"}` as I understand from your question that you want it.  If you want to split that further, you'll need to split each of these strings *again*, this time at `,`.  Note that you'll need to change the type of your array from `String[]` to `String[][]` in this case.  You'll get `{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e"}}`.

If you also want to strip whitespace during the process of splitting, add `\s*` before and after the split character.  For example: `"a, b,c , d".split("\\s*,\\s*")` returns `{"a", "b", "c", "d"}`.

Answer (score 1):

if `myString` is equal to `"a ,b,  c: integer; d,e :real;"` the following with output `a b c d e`

```
for (String type : myString.split(";")) {
  String sub = type.substring(0, type.indexOf(":"));
  for (String name : sub.split(",")) {
    System.out.println(name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem. `temporary.split(",");` is an array then you have appened it to be as a part of another array. Thats troublesome .... I mean:

```
Array
     0 => Array
               0 => a  
               1 => b
```

So you should use:

```
String arr = temporary.split(",");
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DavidConrad what about this?

Comment: Actually, this made your answer even worse.  And in general, editing an answer by replacing it with something completely different is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

how about following?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String str = "a ,b,c: integer;d,e :real;";
    String[] stra = str.split(";");
    for(String st: stra){
        //System.out.println(st);
        String[] stra2 = st.split(",");
        for(String s: stra2){
            System.out.println(s);
            list.add(String.valueOf(s.charAt(0)));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

**OP**

```
a 
b
c: integer
d
e :real
[a, b, c, d, e]
```